# How to make use of tile caching in QGIS using the C++ API?

Tags: qgis, c++, tilecache

I can load TMS Maps using C++ API of QGIS but as zoomIn/zoomOut Map it takes time to show map again.I want it to be smoother. I understand that QGIS has classes like `QgsNetworkDiskCache` or `QgsTileCache` but I don't know how should I use them.

This is my code for loading TMS OSM Map:

```
#include <QApplication>

#include <qgsapplication.h>
#include <qgsmapcanvas.h>
#include <qgsmaplayer.h>
#include <qgsrasterlayer.h>

int  main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // Start the QGIS application
    QgsApplication  app(argc, argv, true);

    QgsApplication::setPluginPath("/usr/lib64");
    QgsApplication::setPrefixPath("/usr", true);
    QgsApplication::setPkgDataPath("/usr/share/qgis");
    app.initQgis();

    // Create a map canvas
    QgsMapCanvas *canvas = new QgsMapCanvas();

    canvas->setWindowTitle("Load TMS map like OSM in QGIS");
    canvas->resize(800, 600);

    // Create a raster layer from a local TMS file
    QString         url   = "type=xyz&zmax=9&zmin=1&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png";// Change this to your TMS file path
    QgsRasterLayer *layer = new QgsRasterLayer(url, "OSM", "wms");

    // Check if the layer is valid
    if (layer->isValid())
    {
        // Add the layer to the project and the canvas
        QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayer(layer);
        canvas->setLayers(QList<QgsMapLayer *>() << layer);

        // Set the canvas extent to the layer extent
        canvas->setExtent(layer->extent());

        // Show the canvas
        canvas->show();
    }
    else
    {
        // Print an error message
        qDebug() << "Unable to load the TMS file.";
    }

    // Start the application loop
    return app.exec();
}
```